# Angular 9 - How to pass array of text data from parent component to multiple layers of child components?

Tags: angular

I am brand new to Angular 9 and am trying to make a form that has, say, 3 different questions each with a series of radio buttons that have differing Likert scale text. Something like:

```
1. "How are you feeling"

Bad - Kind of Bad - Neutral - Somewhat Okay - Good

2. "How worried are you?"

Very worried - somewhat worried - neutral - not really worried - not worried at all

...
```

Currently, I have something like this:

**radio-button.component.html**

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons" [(ngModel)]="radioText">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary white-out">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" /> {{ radioText[0] }}
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary white-out">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" /> {{ radioText[1] }}
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary white-out">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" /> {{ radioText[2] }}
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary white-out">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" /> {{ radioText[3] }}
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary white-out">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" /> {{ radioText[4] }}
    </label>
</div>
```

**radio-button.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'form-radio-buttons',
    templateUrl: './radio-button.component.html',
})
export class RadioButtonComponent {
    @Input() radioText = ['Bad', 'Kind of Bad', 'Neutral', 'Somewhat Okay', 'Good'];
}
```

And this seems to work nicely.

Now, how do I extract that `radioText` up another level and have another parent component pass that in depending on the question?

**app-form.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-form',
    templateUrl: './app-form.component.html',
})
export class FormComponent {
    radioButtonText = [
        ['Bad', 'Kind of Bad', 'Neutral', 'Somewhat Okay', 'Good'],
        ['Very Worried', 'Somewhat worried', 'Neutral', 'Not really worried', 'Not worried at all'],
        ...
    ];
}
```

**app-form.component.html**

```
<form>
    <div>
        <div>How are you feeling</div>
        <form-radio-buttons></form-radio-buttons> <!-- How do I pass the radioButtonText for each set of radio buttons down here? -->
    </div>

    <div>
        <div>How worried are you</div>
        <form-radio-buttons></form-radio-buttons>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: To achieve your goal you should use either services or .json files. Reference: https://angular.io/guide/architecture-services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already defined the radioText as @Input, so in the app-form.component.html you can pass the values to the component using the input binding like below,

`<form-radio-buttons [radioText]="radioButtonText[0]"></form-radio-buttons>`

You can refer,
http://plnkr.co/edit/QORNBHQWnDx6slG6?preview

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!